# Start kippo on Ubuntu startup

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I'm setting up a new Ubuntu 14.04 server and followed [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-kippo-an-ssh-honeypot-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server) to install kippo (the SSH Honeypot).  To run kippo, I do:

```
su kippo
~/kippo/start.sh
```

The contents of start.sh is simply:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Starting kippo in background..."
authbind --deep twistd -y kippo.tac -l log/kippo.log --pidfile kippo.pid
```

Which starts up a background process for kippo.  What can I do to make this automatically run on startup?  Do I need to add a script that calls this in /etc/init.d?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish that, but "The Ubuntu Way" is to write an [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) file.